# Fail to save quad mesh in meshlab

Tags: meshlab

Recently when I try to convert the tri mesh into a quad mesh, I have some difficulties saving it. After exporting my quad mesh, the file seems to be automatically adding Faux edges. Is there a way in meshlab to turn the addition of faux edges off? I have seen people posting about how to perform such actions back in version 2016, but after the update happend at the beginning of the year, I cannot find this option.

Meshlab Ver. 2020.3

Answer (score 1):

In Meshlab, there are certain options which can be set to visualize the newly generated quad elements. I am using the latest version of Meshlab(2020.07) and spent a great deal of time figuring out how to save the quad mesh without the addition of faux edges. First of all, for visualization you can set the "Polygonal Modality" off in the edge mode on the right panel. To save the quad mesh to an .obj file, you can export mesh as OBJ and check the option "Convert triangles to polygons" in the prompted window under additional parameters section. I believe the process is the same for other mesh file types.